# What is meant by the word 'type' in relation to variables?

Tags: java, types

I am working my way through some starter Java using a book and one of the self-assessment questions is:
"What is meant by the word 'type' in relation to variables in Java?"

Stumped me a little bit.

The book states that:
“Reference type variables are declared in the same way as value type variables. First you give the name of the type (the class) and then the name of the variable.”

So my answer is:
The word type, in relation to variables, means creating a name for the class which the variables can be used to reference instances of that class.

For example,

```
Toad frogger;
```

Would result in the type Toad which has a variable, frogger, which can reference instances of the Toad class, or type.

Is this correct?
Thanks for anyone who can clear this up! :)

Comment: Study java a bit more and you'll eventually find out. Programmings not just gonna come to you, you'll have to mess with it. Alot.

Comment: For example, Toad frogger; Would result in a variable frogger of type Toad.

Comment: Variables are like members of a boy band: They have names and types. There the cute one (Jim), the sexy one (Derek), the gay one (Shawn), and the rebel (Kyle). You can replace a variable of any type by a different variable of the same type and the semantics of the program (= band) remain unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

I would say it would be clearer to say that the variable `frogger` is *of* type Toad, which means:

- The compile time type of the expression `frogger` is `Toad` - this is used for things like member resolution when you use `frogger.foo()`, and also if you do `foo(frogger)`
- The value of `frogger` is always either null or a reference to an instance of `Toad` or a subclass. (So the value might be a reference to an instance of `LesserSpottedToad`, for example.)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! That helps clear things up in my head alot :)

Comment: Actually, it's of type _reference to Toad_.

Comment: @TedHopp: No, the type of the expression is `Toad`. The *value* of the expression is only a reference. For example, to quote the spec: "A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T."

Answer (score 0):

`Toad` is the class/type and `frogger` is the reference name. The reference name holds/points to something that could be of type `Toad` or a subclass.

The reference name is also used to call different methods or to access the object, being pointed to by the reference.

Comment: Thank you! That helps. Just wanted clarfication that 'toad' was the type. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. I'd phrase what you said like this:

```
Toad frogger;
```

results in a variable `frogger` which has a type `reference to Toad`. The variable holds a reference to an instance of the `Toad` class (or any object that is *assignment compatible* with Toad — see the [Java Language Specification Sec. 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2) ).

[Chapter 4 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html) has a very nice explanation of the concept of type as used in Java.

Comment: From section 4.12: "A variable of a class type T can hold a null reference or a reference to an instance of class T or of any class that is a subclass of T." That's not "A variable of reference to a class type T" - it's "A variable of a class Type T"